# Xubuntu freezes whenever opening Chromium

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, xubuntu, chromium

I have Xubuntu 20.04 installed on my IdeaPad gaming Core i5 and GeForce GTX. I don't understand why with the given specs my machine is still slow and many times it freezes. I tried to Google it, and it says that it's because of snap and I have my Chromium installed as a snap package. If I uninstalled the snap package completely and install Chromium through something else, would that help or even upgraded to 22.04 would the freezing problem away?

Here is the full information of my PC.

```
- 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
- 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
- 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
- 00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
- 00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
- 00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
- 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
- 00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
- 00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
- 00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
- 00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
- 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
- 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
- 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
- 00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
- 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
- 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
- 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
- 00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
- 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
- 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
- 0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Comment: Only you can tell trying the suggestions you made. Information is too vague for anyone being able to pinpoint the cause. You do not indicate available memory. With low memory and swap on a traditional hard drive, swapping can slow down the system, although it should not permanently freeze.

Comment: @vanadium, I edited my question with the information. Is it like that?